# ListView's onEndReached not working when inside a View

Tags: react-native, reactjs

Here is the thing. 
I want to render a listview that updates the data when onEndReached.

While the data is updated, I want to render a 'loading' text below the list (without removing the list).   like this:

```
render() {
  var {isFetching} = this.props.query
  var loading
  if(isFetching){
    loading = this.renderLoading()
  }
  return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderItem}
        onEndReached={this.props.fetchNextPage}
        onEndReachedThreshold={10}
        style={styles.listView} />
      {loading}
  )
}
renderLoading () {
  return (
    <View style={styles.loading}>
      <ActivityIndicatorIOS
        size='large'/>
      <Text>
        Loading books...
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

But soon I realised that the render function has to return a single element. So I tried this:

```
return (
    <View>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderItem}
        onEndReached={this.props.fetchNextPage}
        onEndReachedThreshold={10}
        style={styles.listView}/>
      {loading}
    </View>  
  )
```

But then the onEndReached fired again and again and again as soon as it was mounted. Even before I touched the screen.

How can I achieve the loading view, while keeping the 'infinite scroll' behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I finally used a workaround. I rendered the loading view as the footer of the listView.

Comment: onEndReached still fired again and again and again

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  Remove the enclosing <View> and render whatever you want in the renderFooter() method

Answer (score 1):

you can try to give ListView a height(eg:height:300)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to render it as the listView footer. Try giving the wrapping view style: {flex: 1}:

```
return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderItem}
        onEndReached={this.props.fetchNextPage}
        onEndReachedThreshold={10}
        style={styles.listView}/>
      {loading}
    </View>  
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons for your list to be rendering again and again could be the  value of `onEndReachedThreshold={10}` here.

For values more than or equal 1, the method in `onEndReached` is going to be called as soon as render is called.

Set a value say 0.5 which would mean that `onEndReached` method is going to be invoked when half of the current list is scrolled.